# API vs readonly mysql user (updating data from one app to another)

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, synchronization

I have two applications, first in PHP Symfony, second in Rails.
Both on their own independent app&db servers.

In my Rails app I need to update regularly **3 tables** from the first app DB (get all records, check if changed/added and update rails DB) :

```
SERVER1 [MySQL DB1 -> APP1 (in php)]
           ||
           || <--copy with some processing
           \/
SERVER2 [MySQL DB2 -> APP2 (in rails)]
```

I consider two options:

1. Build PHP API to receive data from SERVER1 DB.
2. Create mysql user with read-only access to needed tables in DB1 and than use it (with `establish_connection`) in rails models representing remote DB.

In second solution I need to open TCP/IP port in source server, but in first i need to write API with authorization.

What are advantages/disadvantages of both? (Performance? Security? Stability? Scalability? etc.)

Comment: Ever thought about using binary logs for replication or clustering? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

Comment: Also take a look at using rsync over ssh http://www.jdmz.net/ssh/

Comment: yes but I need to verify/modify data received from DB1, so I don't want replication.

Comment: Suggestion was to setup a master slave replication to SERVER 2, then do a local DB1 to DB2 copy with processing. With rsync you can setup a script to update a rotating log file on SERVER1 then use rsync on SERVER2 to pull the files for processing (v-quick). The connection is via ssh and log files are not accessible via web, so data is secure.